# How can I compare multiple rows in R?

Tags: r

I would like to compare multiple values by USER.

Based on USER "A", If the values (A,B,C,D,and E) are same with USER "B", it should be written as B at the newly created variable EQUAL

Here is my data

[image]

Desired value

[image]

I am very new to R, I tried to look at the compare function but got a little overwhelmed. Would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide reproducible sample data using structure() or dput()? Also, what if one line of A is equal to both B and C?

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.   No one wants to type it all in again.  Instead,  use `dput` to make a text version of your data and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an abridged version of the data you provided:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1001, 1002, 1003),
  user = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  point_a = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA),
  point_b = c(NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA),
  point_c = c(3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3),
  point_d = c(2, 1, NA, 2, 1, NA),
  point_e = c(4, NA, 1, 4, NA, NA)
)

df

    id user point_a point_b point_c point_d point_e
1 1001    a       1      NA       3       2       4
2 1002    a       1      NA       2       1      NA
3 1003    a      NA       2       3      NA       1
4 1001    b       1      NA       3       2       4
5 1002    b       1      NA       2       1      NA
6 1003    b      NA      NA       3      NA      NA
```

If you `inner_join` on the columns you want to match, and then `filter` for rows where `user.x` is greater than `user.y` (i.e. first in alphabetical order, to get rid of duplicates and rows matching to themselves), you should be left with the matches you're looking for:

```
df %>%
  inner_join(df, by = c('point_a', 'point_b', 'point_c', 'point_d', 'point_e')) %>%
  filter(user.x < user.y) %>%
  rename(user = user.x,
         equal = user.y)

  id.x user point_a point_b point_c point_d point_e id.y equal
1 1001    a       1      NA       3       2       4 1001     b
2 1002    a       1      NA       2       1      NA 1002     b
```

Answer (score 0):

We may `split` the data along users, and put the result in `mapply` and calculate the `rowSums` of `TRUE`s after comparison with `` `==` ``. From the resulting matrix we want to know `which.max` which allows us to subset the users (without `"A"`). The result just needs to be subsetted by user `"A"`.

```
transform(dat, EQUAL=
            split(dat, dat$user) |>
            (\(.) mapply(\(x, y) rowSums(x == y, na.rm=TRUE), 
                         unname(.['A']), 
                         .[c('B', 'C')]))() |>
            (\(.) sort(unique(dat$user))[-1][apply(., 1, which.max)])()
) |>
  (\(.) .[.$user == 'A', ])()
#     id user point_a point_b point_c point_d point_e EQUAL
# 1 1001    A       1      NA       3       2       4     B
# 2 1002    A       1      NA       2       1      NA     B
# 3 1003    A      NA       2       3      NA       1     C
```

**Note:** `R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)`

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1001L, 1002L, 1003L, 1001L, 1002L, 1003L, 
1001L, 1002L, 1003L), user = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C"), point_a = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 4, 1, NA), point_b = c(NA, 
NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 2), point_c = c(3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
2, 3), point_d = c(2, 1, NA, 2, 1, NA, 2, 1, NA), point_e = c(4, 
NA, 1, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```